Is the minimum of nontrivial sums of independent, continuous, non-negative random variables, again continuous?
We are given independent, absolutely¹ continuously distributed and non-negative real random variables $X_i$ for $i=1,\dots, N$. Here, absolutely¹ continuously distributed means that there exists $\delta_i$ such that $\mathbb P (X_i \leq z) = \int_0^z \delta_i(x) \,\mathrm dx$ for all $z\in\mathbb R$.
For $j= 1,\dots, M$, we define $Y_j$ as a non-trivial sum of the form $Y_j = \sum_{i\in I_j} X_i$ with $I_J\neq \emptyset$, and all $(I_j)_j$ are pairwise distinct.
Question: Is $Z=\min_j Y_j$ absolutely¹ continuously distributed?
Attempts: For $M=2$ this seems to be true, as we may remove occurrences of $X_i$ that are present in both $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ (and obtain $Y_1'$ and $Y_2'$).
After this, $Y_1'$ or $Y_2'$ (but not both) may be zero in which case we are finished (as all nontrivial sums are continuously distributed: convolution of densities).
Otherwise, $Y_1'$ and $Y_2'$ are independent and continuously distributed. Thus, their joint distribution is absolutely continuous and we can write $$\mathbb P(\min (Y_1', Y_2') \leq z) = \mathbb P(Y_1' \leq z) + \mathbb P(Y_2' \leq z) - \mathbb P(Y_1' \leq z , Y_2' \leq z)$$ which is again absolutely continuous in $z$.
However, I do not know how to expand this approach beyond $M=2$.
Edit:
[¹] Added term absolutely for absolutely continuously distributed variables.

What you call "continuously distributed" is usually called "absolutely continuous", and there is a nice test for it provided by the Radon Nikodym Theorem: It is equivalent to
$P(X \in A)=0$ for every set of Lebesgue measure zero.
A sum of a sequence of (independent) variables where at least one is absolutely continuous will be absolutely continuous (condition on the other variables first). I assumed independence as that was assumed in the question, but I should have emphasized this condition. Therefore this test immediately implies a positive answer to your question.
Edit: Fact 1: If $X,Y$ are independent and $X$ is absolutely continuous, then $X+Y$ is absolutely continuous.
Proof: For $A$ in $\mathbb R $ of Leb. measure zero, $$P(X+Y \in A)=\int P(X  \in A-y) dF_Y(y)=0\,.$$
Fact 2: If $X,Y$ are  both  absolutely continuous, then $\min(X,Y)$ is absolutely continuous. (Independence not needed here).
Proof: For $A$ in $\mathbb R $ of Leb. measure zero, a union bound gives $$P(\min(X,Y) \in A) \le  P(X  \in A )+P(Y \in A)=0\,.  $$

Thanks for the answer! I understand the Radon-Nikodym-Test, however I do not yet understand how to apply it here.
Also, the sum of two absolutely continuously distributed random variables is not necessarily absolutely continuously distributed (e.g. X + (-X)), so I am still struggling to understand your answer. Could you give me another hint how this relates to the minimum of the sums? Thanks again!

Ah, I understand how to apply the Radon-Nykodym-Test now (I still don't understand your second sentence, but it seems irrelevant to me):
Let $X$ and $Y$ be two abs. continuously distributed variables, and let $A$ be any set of measure zero.
Wlog. $\mathbb P( X > Y) > 0$ (otherwise $\min(X,Y)=Y$) and $\mathbb P(X \leq Y) > 0$.
Then, we have $\mathbb P(\min(X,Y) \in A)=\mathbb P(X \in A  | X < Y) + \mathbb P(Y \in A | X \geq Y) = 0$.
Thus, $\min(X,Y)$ is abs. continuously distributed.
Is this your expected way to prove this?

A sum of independent variables where at least one of them is absolutely continuous, is abs. cont.  I edited my answer to explain this. Also the absolute continuity of a minimum is very simple, I added the explanation.
